# How can I retrieve and send CSRF token from Firebase server for user authentication?

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions, session-cookies, third-party-cookies

Firebase server not creating csrfToken

Hi everyone,

I'm currently struggling with the firebase documentation. I want to provide instagram authentication on my platform.

But as I understand, I got to secure my request with a csrftoken.
I am currently trying to follow the documentation to be able to send csrftoken through my cookies when a user log in.

I reached to the point where I can retrieve the idtoken of my users, but not the csrfToken.
I think it's not automatically sent by firebase, but I cannot figure how to send it from my firebase server. So the next step would be to use this csrftoken in my requests.

I work in typescript (angular 12 + node.js on server) and tried several things like...

Here is my frontend :

I try so send my idtoken to my server but the csrfToken is always null...

```
anonymousLogIn(){
    return new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
      const prevUrl = window.location.href;
      console.log(prevUrl);
      this.fireAuth.setPersistence(inMemoryPersistence).then(()=>{
        signInAnonymously(this.fireAuth).then((user)=>{
          if(user) console.log(user);
          getIdToken(user.user).then((idtoken)=>{
            console.log("idtoken : "+idtoken);

            //what to do to retrieve this csrfToken and how to send ot from server ????
            const csrfToken = this.getCookie("csrfToken");
            //window.location.assign('https://us-central1-le-maki-55.cloudfunctions.net/createCookie?idToken='+idtoken+'&csrfToken='+csrfToken+'&prevUrl='+prevUrl);
            //this.router.navigate(['createCookie'], {queryParams: {idToken: idtoken, csrfToken: csrfToken}});
            //window.location.assign()
            //this.setCookies({idToken: idtoken, csrfToken: csrfToken}).then((cookie)=>{
            //  console.log('cookies : '+cookie)
            //});
            console.log(csrfToken);
          });
          resolve;
        },(error)=>{
          reject(error);
        });
      });
    });
  }

  private getCookie(name: string) {
    var v = document.cookie.match('(^|;) ?' + name + '=([^;]*)(;|$)');
    return v ? v[2] : null;
  }
```

Here is my backend :

This functions may help me to attach the csrftoken to my requests

```
app.use("/", (req, res, next)=>{
  const headerToken = req.header("Authorization");
  if (!headerToken) {
    res.status(401).send({message: "Auth token must be provided"});
    return;
  }
  const headerParts = headerToken.split(" ");
  if (headerParts.length < 2 || headerParts[0] !== "Bearer" || !headerParts[1]) {
    res.status(401).send({message: "Invalid token"});
    return;
  }
  admin
      .auth()
      .verifyIdToken(headerParts[1])
      .then((decodedToken) => {
        console.log("decoded token :");
        console.log(decodedToken);
        next();
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        res.status(403).send({message: error.message}).end();
      });
});

app.get("/", async (req, res) => {
  res.status(200).send("Request executed successfully").end();
});
```

But I cannot find the way to receive/send this csrftoken from my firebase server. The documentation said that you log in your user and you should be sending/receiving the csrftoken at this time... But how can I do it ? I really can't understand the official docs.

I would be very grateful to the ones who'll try to give me advices.